# Cannot resolve DatabaseReference Firebase Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am very confused why my code won't resolve DatabaseReference. I looked up some solutions which is adding :

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'

but I have those already

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView title, subtitle, klogonok;

    DatabaseReference reference;
```

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```